# Fireworks symbol scripts created in CS5.5 are not working in CC6

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I have a library of custom Fireworks symbols which had symbol scripts allowing me to control the display attributes of elements and text via the Symbol Properties panel. The symbols and the scripts were created using Fireworks CS5.5 using the built in script editor.

When loading the same exact scripts into Fireworks CC6 they appear in the common symbol library but when they are added to the document the Symbol properties panel does not display the scripted options.

I have tried opening the script in the editor in the CC6 version and resaving with no change in behavior.

Does anyone:

1. See the same behavior (i do not see any help articles / issues on
   Adobe.com)
2. Have a fix for the broken symbol scripts